# VC++ command line arguments are being ignored

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I am attempting to get someone else's VC++ project to work in VC8.  The solution contains both a library and an executable.  Each project is located in its own directory one level below the solution.  When the code is compiled, the executable is placed in a debug folder under the solution folder rather than in the programdir\debug folder.

Here is the layout:

```
solutiondir\solution.sln
solutiondir\libdir\library.proj (and .cpp and .h files)
solutiondir\programdir\program.proj (and main.cpp)
solutiondir\debug\library.lib
solutiondir\debug\program.exe
```

Everything builds fine, but when I try to run program.exe, there is a problem that I am trying to debug.  When I first started trying to run program.exe in debug mode, it asked me where the exe was located, so I browsed to the debug directory (solutiondir\debug), then the debugger was able to run program.exe.  So far, so good.

The problem is that I can't get past the "usage" function because the command line arguments are not being picked up.  I edited the properties of the program and there are definitely arguments in there, but argc == 1 and the only argument is the program name, a clear indication that the "Command Arguments" are being ignored or not found.

I am wondering if the problem has something to do with the directory structure or whether there is some variable like $(target) that needs to be set, though I tried setting that already.  Am I missing something?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the project that builds program.exe set as the default project?  That's the one it runs when you start debugging.  If a DLL is the default it'll ask for the executable.

Comment: My advice in this situation is to recreate the projects from scratch. Don't rely on Visual Studio's automatic conversion of projects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 'properties of the program' but in VS2013 (sorry don't have VC8) the program arguments for debugging are set in Properties/Configuration Properties/Debugging/Command Arguments. And don't forget to set these for the debug configuration.

Comment: Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm, changing the startup project fixed the command arguments problem. I am now able to debug the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the project that builds the program executable as the default project, and that will be what runs when you start debugging.